# How to find field embeddings

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> What are the field embeddings from $K\to\bar{\mathbb Q}$ and how can I use these to compute $N_{K/\mathbb Q}(a)$ and $T_{K/\mathbb Q}(a)$, with $K=\mathbb Q({\sqrt[3]{2}})$ and $a={\sqrt[3]{2}}+3$

Now an embedding is a homomorphism between $2$ fields, and here the closure of $\mathbb Q$ is I think $\mathbb R$

Since I had to find the norm and the trace in a different way (with a matrix which is the same as multiplication by a), If I look at the formula below, I guess there should be $3$ such embeddings, because I obtained a $3\times3$ matrix in the previous case.

$N_{K/\mathbb Q}(a)=\prod\limits_{i=1}^{d}\sigma_i(a)$, $\quad$$T_{K/\mathbb Q}(a)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{d}\sigma_i(a)$

but I have some difficulties to determine them, so any element of $K$, say $r+s{\sqrt[3]{2}}+t{\sqrt[3]{4}}$ is sent to $\mathbb R$, id should be for example one, since its a homomorphism. How can I continue ?

Comment: $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ usually means the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$, not $\mathbb{R}$. It's not a topological closure. You can consider $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ as a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ generated by the roots of all polynomials with rational coefficients. Then your other two embeddings would send $\sqrt[3]{2}$ to the two complex roots of $x^3-2$.

Comment: @Prometheus and there are no other possibilities ?

Comment: No, because any such embedding is determined by where it sends $\sqrt[3]{2}$, and since that number satisfies $x^2-3=0$ any image of it must also satisfy that equation.

Comment: If I denote the complex roots with $x_1,x_2$ then $r+s{\sqrt[3]{2}}+t{\sqrt[3]{4}}\mapsto r+x_is{\sqrt[3]{2}}+x_i^2t{\sqrt[3]{4}}$ could be the other embeddings, but I get the wrong result.

Comment: The embeddings are $r + s \sqrt[3]{2} + t\sqrt[3]{4} \mapsto r + sx_i + tx_i^2$

Comment: From the above it must be clear now that you are *not* looking for embeddings $\;K\to\overline{\Bbb Q}\;$ but in fact for embedding $\;K'\to\overline{\Bbb Q}\;$ , with $\;K'\;$ the Galois closure of $\;K\;$ over $\;\Bbb Q\;$, as otherwise there is only one single embedding $\;K\to\overline{\Bbb Q}\;$ : the identity morphism one.